# Regex: number and comma alternation between double quotes

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex that matches a `"1,2,3,10,12312"` pattern.

As I understand it would start with `/([""'])` to match the double quotes but I'm lost when I try to get to the \d digit and comma alternation.

what would be a valid regex to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some choices, one being:

```
"\d+(?:,\d+)*"
```

To even allow empty double quotes (`""`), change the expression to

```
"\d*(?:,\d+)*"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/KRght8/1).

Comment: Your second one will allow a leading comma.  You could use `"(?:|\d+(?:,\d+)*)"` to allow empties